# If in a LAN network there is a machine with the wrong mask, what happens to communication to and from this machine?

Tags: networking, netmask

Just a theory question I've come across. As the title says, what happens to communication to and from a machine with a wrong netmask?

I suppose it would work in leaving communications but not in entering ones.

Comment: If device A has the right mask, and device B has not, device A will see device B and it can initiate a connection to device B. While Device B can receive the packets, it doesn't see A and cannot respond back to it. Depending on the type of communication, it may or may not work.